Alembic configuration using Environment variables
I've been having trouble with database configuration using Alembic considering I am using environment variables and my password has a special character.
Is there an easier way to do it other than encoding the password then replacing every % sign with %%
I have tried encoding the password to "remove" the special character then replacing every %  from the encoded password with %% as in the code below:
db_password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(f"{settings.db_password}"). replace("%","%%")
After which I pass the password into the set_main_option function for the sqlachemy url as in the code below:
config.set_main_option("sqlachemy.url", f'postgres+psycopg2://{settings.db_user}:{db_password}@{settings.db_host}:{settings.db_port}/{settings.db_name}')

Why are you doing .replace('%', '%%')?

@snakecharmerb Appears to be a limitation caused by alembic using ConfigParser.set -- alembic.config.Config.set_main_option

This seems almost undocumented but maybe was the intention but it seems that you can use sqlalchemy.engine.URL to help with this.

Try creating-urls-programmatically from the env passing the raw (unquoted) values.
Use render_as_string with hide_password=False to combine the env into a string URL.
Escape % with %% for alembic.

Maybe something like this:
db_url = URL.create(
  'postgres+psycopg2',
  username=settings.db_user,
  password=settings.db_password,
  host=settings.db_host,
  port=settings.db_port,
  database=settings.db_name)
db_url_str = db_url.render_as_string(hide_password=False)
escaped_db_url_str = db_url_str.replace("%", "%%")
config.set_main_option("sqlachemy.url", escaped_db_url_str)

I use alembic by calling config.set_main_option("sqlachemy.url", env['DATABASE_URL']) so I think it is almost an accident I have not run into this problem.  I am both not escaping the password as well as not escaping the %.
Note that you can pass db_url created from URL.create directly to create_engine in your application code so maybe you could re-use something from your main app in alembic to do that part.  Like this:
from myapp.db import get_url
# not sure where settings comes from here but the contents
# of get_url would be like the URL.create call above but in your myapp.db module
db_url = get_url(settings)
db_url_str = db_url.render_as_string(hide_password=False)
escaped_db_url_str = db_url_str.replace("%", "%%")
config.set_main_option("sqlachemy.url", escaped_db_url_str)

